# How to get info from multiple widgets hovered over simoultaneously?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

**Issue**

As per the drawing below I have a 4x4 grid of Widgets. The red line indicates the touch gesture I make. The green coloured squares are the squares the gesture touches. The blue coloured squares are the ones not touched by the gesture.

How can I make flutter get all the widgets i touch this way and store a reference so that I can access their content (for example an image or a string)?

**What did I do so far?**

I was looking at the "Draggable" widget type, it works for dragging a single widget and I could get that to work with a single widget. But I could not get it to work with multiple widgets being dragged over/touched this way. So I suspect I may need another solution. At this time I am just not sure what could make this functionality work.

**Example image**

[image: 4x4 grid of widgets]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can wrap the `Container` by `GestureDetector` and maintain the state `onTap` of each container in a custom model list.

Comment: Is tap not only for when you tap on top of it and not when you tap elsewhere and drag over it?

Comment: Did you check the answer?

Comment: Hi, I did not get to check the answer as I decided to go with a different approach using React instead of Flutter.

But thank you very much. If I should decide on Flutter at some point I will be sure to get back to you.

I will give you an upvote for contribution but cannot select it as the right answer as I have changed my approach to a different framework.

Comment: Do you think it's easier to do with React? I never used it.

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: https://youtu.be/sBws8MSXN7A <-- A relatively quick breakdown of what React is like.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below example. You may need to modify it as per your requirement.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark()
          .copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47)),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: CustomPage());
  }
}

class CustomPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return CustomPageState();
  }
}

class CustomPageState extends State<CustomPage> {
  double progress = 0;

  var arr = [
    [false, false, false],
    [false, false, false],
    [false, false, false]
  ];

  var keys = [
    [new GlobalKey(), new GlobalKey(), new GlobalKey()],
    [new GlobalKey(), new GlobalKey(), new GlobalKey()],
    [new GlobalKey(), new GlobalKey(), new GlobalKey()]
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.blueAccent,
      child: Center(
        //Wraps the second container in RawGestureDetector
        child: Center(
            child: GestureDetector(
          onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) {
            changeState(details.globalPosition);
          },
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: List.generate(
                3,
                (i) => Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: List.generate(
                          3,
                          (j) => Container(
                                key: keys[i][j],
                                margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                                color: arr[i][j] ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
                                width: 50,
                                height: 50,
                              )),
                    )),
          ),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }

  void changeState(Offset pos) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        Rect re = _getWidgetGlobalRect(keys[i][j]);
        if (re.contains(pos)) {
          selectItem(i, j);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  Rect _getWidgetGlobalRect(GlobalKey key) {
    RenderBox renderBox = key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    var offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    return Rect.fromLTWH(
        offset.dx, offset.dy, renderBox.size.width, renderBox.size.height);
  }

  void selectItem(int i, int j) {
    if (arr[i][j]) {
      return;
    }
    setState(() {
      arr[i][j] = !arr[i][j];
    });
  }
}
```

[image]